# "PC Sync" is disabled again in calendar after locked screen

Tags: sync, calendar

I sync my contacts and events over my pc with thunderbird on it.
My phone: HTC One S, Android 4.0.3 with HTC Sense 4.0 and using GO Launcher EX 2.87.

Problem is that after enabled the calender checkbox to show me "PC-Sync"-data in calendar-app it does always disable this again after screen was locked.

Any suggestions what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i have figured out myself what caused the problem, thanks anyway:

I tried uninstalling some apps i installed before and looks like "Business Calendar Free Beta" caused this problem. After i removed it, it works just fine and normal.
And i didn't liked it anyway and i think the standard app is good for me.